# Cannot read disk sectors in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, bios

I am trying to read disk sectors by the following code:

```
disk_load :
push dx 

mov ah , 0x02 ; BIOS read sector function
mov al , dh ; Read DH sectors(dh is initialized before calling the routine)
mov ch , 0x01 ;
mov dh , 0x00 ; Select head 0
mov cl , 0x02 ; Start reading from second sector ( i.e.
; after the boot sector )

mov dl,0x80 (tried with 0x00 as well)

int 0x13 ; BIOS interrupt

pop dx ; Restore DX from the stack
jc cset

cmp dh,al ; if AL ( sectors read ) != DH ( sectors expected )
jne disk_error ;
```

Problem is ,Carry flag is set every time denoting an error. Initially I tried boot disk 0x00 which when I checked AL register afterwards found out that no sectors are being read. Then I changed to 0x80 ,now AL register would have the exact number of sectors requested but still Carry flag is being set!

So what could be the problem here? Carry seems to be set always after int 0x13!
I am running an iso file in Virtual Box if that matters.

Comment: The instructions seems to have disordered a bit once I posted the question. However I have written exactly like i Found them in certain tutorials.

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: @mbratch I am running Windows 7. Trying my hand at OS Developement.

Comment: Minimal working GAS example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/5c2e547b524e6d0f4217780e2036ec525d6b205c/bios_disk_load.S Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065370/how-to-load-second-stage-boot-loader-from-first-stage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a sector from hard drive with int 13h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497842/read-a-sector-from-hard-drive-with-int-13h)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some hints:

1. You should load `CH` with zero, not one, beause cylinders are numbered from zero.
2. Upon failure an error code is returned in `AH`, have you looked at that?
3. Booting from cd (iso as you say) complicates things, in particular check if you have floppy emulation enabled. Or just use a virtual floppy until you get things right.
4. The BIOS usually passes the boot drive for you in `DL` so there should be no need to overwrite that.

Using floppy image and fixing point #1, it works for me with bochs and qemu (don't have virtualbox).

Comment: Hey it works just like you said! I used floppy emulation :) Why does iso complicate things? Thank you by the way. Was stuck with this for 2 days.:)

Comment: cdroms are not normally accessible using `int 13/02`, but the `El torito` bootable cdrom specification allows for floppy or hd emulation (needs BIOS support of course). You just have to be careful about it but you didn't post any details about how you create the iso.

Comment: I compile the asm file using nasm. Convert .bin file to .flp file and use mkisofs to make an iso. And run in virtual box. No CD ROM as such but just the image.

Comment: @CiroSantilli the `CLEAR` macro in [common.h](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/5c2e547b524e6d0f4217780e2036ec525d6b205c/common.h#L35) destroys `DX` and thereby `DL`.