# Parameter error when using INT 13h when creating a bootloader

Tags: operating-system, nasm, qemu, bootloader

I am following this [guide](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Eexr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) to try to learn more about operating systems. I am at the part where I am using the BIOS to read disk sectors. However, when I use `int 0x13`, I receive an error. The value in `AH=01h`, meaning there is an invalid parameter somewhere. I have read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381434/cannot-read-disk-sectors-in-assembly-language?rq=3) thread, but it did not help. I set my cylinder to 0(`CH=0`). Here is my code so far(I am using NASM to assemble and QEMU to emulate):

boot_sect.asm

```
[org 0x7c00]
    xor ax, ax          
    mov ds, ax          
    mov bx, boot_string ;test print with booting message
    call print_string   ;print the statement
    ;We are now setting up disk reading
    mov bp, 0x8000      ;move stack out of the way
    mov sp, bp          ;match stack pointer

    mov bx, 0x9000
    mov es, bx
    mov dh, 5
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    call disk_load
    jmp $

%include "string.asm"
%include "hex.asm"
%include "disk.asm"

BOOT_DRIVE: db 0x00

boot_string: db "Booting OS...", 0xA, 0xD, 0

    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55

    times 256 dw 0xdada
    times 256 dw 0xface
```

disk.asm

```
disk_load:
    push dx
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, dh
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x02
    int 0x13
    jc disk_error
    pop dx
    cmp dh, al
    jne disk_error
    ret

disk_error:
    mov bx, disk_error_msg
    call print_string 
    mov dl, ah
    mov dh, 0
    call print_hex
    jmp $

disk_error_msg: db "Disk read error: ", 0
```

Here is a picture of the error: [QEMU error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGOzh.png)

I don't know where I went wrong. I checked to make sure my cylinder, head and sector are correct, and I can't find any problems with it. I am not sure which of the parameters I am passing are incorrect.

Comment: You're passing `dh` = 5. That seems to be wrong. `dh` holds the CHS head. If you're running off a standard 1440 KiB 90mm diskette image then you do not have 6 heads.